# Does PSVita remote play let me use it as an additional controller?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita

I recently bought the Remote-Play enabled Pixeljunk Eden, and since I have one PS3 controller and one Vita, I was wondering how exactly remote play works (I'm interested in trying Eden's co-op).

Does everyone need to use Remote-Play, or must everyone? Is there a limit to the number of Remote-Play-ers, or are they just as good as having actual controllers? Does any of this vary by game?

Comment: I never thought of using Remote Play like this...it's fairly rare that games support it (or it was years ago, with the PSP)...I'll see if it works tonight.

Comment: There's at least one instance you can use Vita as a PS3 controller on a PS3 game, it doesn't involve Remote Play, though http://www.joystiq.com/2012/02/13/video-the-vita-becomes-a-ps3-controller-in-ultimate-marvel-vs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how remote play works, it simply allows you to control the PS3 from the Vita from any location you have internet access.

Basically it displays what would have been on the TV screen on the Vita Screen but not every game supports this feature. You can however switch the PS3 on from standby and access the XMB.

Two player is not possible via remote play unless it is online.

Edit:
Now that the Vita has been updated to firmware version 2.0 there is an option called 'cross-controller' under the remote play button. Apparently you need to download software from a game that supports this feature in order for it to work. I would assume that future games plan to use this feature.

I can't find any more information at this point, I just stumbled across it after I updated.

Comment: Well, crap. I totally misunderstood what Remote Play was. :/